# React, run deploy, git hub pages routing problem

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

Im using React JS, trying to deploy an app on git hub pages. but Im having a routing problem. App just doesnt load well. I have to click "Inicio" to start using the app

```
https://nam3216.github.io/serigrafia/
```

I read that in react´s older version, this issue could be solved adding this to Router on App.js

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  {/* routes */}
</Router>
```

But it doesnt seem to work now. Any ideas how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, just found it! thanx!. By the way, now I have another problem, images on index page wont work...I guess its something related to image new routing...

Comment: You may want to post a new question on SO regarding the specific issue with the images.